# Get stdout from an idle background application in Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, scheduled-tasks

I have an ffmpeg.exe process that appears to be hung - it hasn't done anything for several days. It was started by exec() in PHP, so is running in the background and has no window.

I would like to know what caused it to stop/hang.

Is there anyway to get what it has written to stdout?

Comment: Has this ffmpeg invocation outputted anything?

Comment: I expect it has, but I have not written it out to a file or captured it in my code. The process has not terminated, I would imagine it's sitting there with an error

Comment: Or more likely, waiting with a prompt. Can you send `y` or `n` to it?

Comment: According to the documentation, PHP collects the output from exec() processes.  So it will be sitting in a buffer somewhere in the PHP process.  In principle I guess you could launch a debugger or write a program that uses ReadProcessMemory to look for it, if you have some idea of what to look for.  Windows doesn't keep a separate log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand you correctly, but I'll try.

If you wanna see its output, you can hook its output functions via IAT/inline hooking and redirect it to a file or something.

However, I think you just wanna see what it is doing. In that case I suggest you to use "Procmon" from the "[Sysinternals Suit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb545027)".

Comment: The problem is, I don't think it's doing anything, and I was not logging it's output to a file when the process was started.

Comment: I'm wondering if the output it has already created is stored anywhere and can be accessed - something like: `ShowStdErr/Out [PID]`

Comment: I still think you should run Procmon and check if it's still doing somthing. Anyway, you can dump the process and then use "Strings" on it (also form "Sysinternals")

Comment: I have now dumped the process, but not sure how to see what it has output. I have run Strings on it, but I don't seem to be able to see the error ffmpeg has given